# The method should print the array elements between the indexes a and b including a and not including b in line 1

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, void

I don't know how to finish this code. Help someone.

```
package com.telukhin.hw4;

import java.util.Arrays;
public class Task10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        list(arr, 2, 5);
    }
    private static void list(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
        if (a >= 0 && b <= arr.length) {
            for (int i = a; i < arr[b - 1]; i++) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("unknown");
        }
    }
} //
```

Comment: finish what? What's the problem? You need to explain what is wrong, what you expect, what you get.

Comment: `i < arr[b - 1]` This condition in your loop is incorrect. Probably should be just `i  < b-1` or something along those lines.

Comment: When I try to print my array, nothing is shown at all

Comment: but i expected to see elements between A and B in the array, A and B it is indices of cells in the array

Comment: Oh, and you need to assign some numbers to your array, it is empty in it's current state. And `Arrays.toString(arr)` prints the whole array at once, so you're printing everything `n` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your array is empty. Take a look at the code below. In the for loop I'm checking that the index is between param a and b (including a, excluding b), and simply printing out the current index.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 2;
    arr[3] = 3;
    arr[4] = 4;
    arr[5] = 5;

    list(arr, 2, 5);
}

private static void list(int[] arr, int a, int b) {
    if (a >= 0 && b <= arr.length) {
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("unknown");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeea, it is exactly I wanted

Answer (score 0):

In your example you try to combine to approaches

1. Custom implementation

Iterate the interval and print each element

```
for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

2. Existing implementation

```
int[] subArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, a, b);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(subArr));
```

You should use only one